# Python 3 recognizing float with type()

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

This is a piece of code I encountered in the 7th lecture on introduction to computer science on MIT OCW. This small program gets input for base and height then calculate the hypotenuse with Pythagoras theorem.

For some reason, it couldn't recognize entry of float.

The code is as follows:

```
#! /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5
import math

#Get base
inputOK = False
while not inputOK:
    base = input("Enter base: ")
    if type(base) == type(1.0):
        inputOK = True
    else:
        print("Error. Base must be a floating point number.")

#Get Height
inputOK = False
while not inputOK:
    height = input("Enter height: ")
    if type(height) == type(1.0):
        inputOK = True
    else:
        print("Error. height must be a floating point number.")

hyp = math.sqrt(base*base + height*height)

print("Base: " + str(base) + ", height: " + str(height) + ", hypotenuse:" + str(hyp))
```

Answer (score 6):

This is one of those cases where it is easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. Instead of trying to look at the object and assert it is a float before you act, try to use it as a float and catch any exceptions.

That is, instead of using `if`s use:

```
try:
    base = float(base)
    inputOK = True
except ValueError as e:
    print("Error. Base must be a floating point number.")
```

This applies similarly to the `height` value you're trying to get afterwards.

Regardless, `input()` returns a string so `type(input())` will always return `str`. It is better to cast it to a float (note: `int`s are also applicable and will be made to floats) and see if it is acceptable than trying to discern its type with `if` checks.

Mandatory aside, if you even need to check for types, don't use `type(obj_a) == type(obj_b)`, it is arguably always better to use `isinstance(obj_a, type(obj_b))`.

Answer (score 3):

The code appears to be written for **Python 2**, not Python 3, as it requires `input()` to return something *other* than a string. In Python 3, `input()` always returns a string, it never applies `eval()` to that result like Python 2 would.

It has other issues as well, like using `type(base) == type(1.0)`, completely ignoring the availability of the `float` object and using `is` to test for identity, and misses out completely on the far superior `isinstance()` function.

Just use exception handling instead:

```
while True:
    try:
        base = float(input("Enter base: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Error. Base must be a floating point number.")
```

Note that there is no need for a `inputOK` boolean either.